# How to unlisten MDCDialog event

Tags: material-components, material-components-web

I have a small function which listen to `MDCDialog:closing`.

The problem is, each time I run this function, it add a new listener.
So, I need to remove this same listener once I'm done using it.

So far, this is what I did:

```
function confirm() {
    mdcAlert.open();
    // start listening
    mdcAlert.listen("MDCDialog:closing", function(event) {
        {... execute what need to be done ...}

        // stop listening (not working)
        mdcAlert.unlisten("MDCDialog:closing");
    });
}
```

Do you happen to know how to use `unlisten`?

I can't figure out how to use it in the doc:
https://material.io/develop/web/components/dialogs/
https://pub.dev/documentation/mdc_web/latest/mdc_web/MDCComponent/unlisten.html

Comment: Can you check if there's already a listener and then only add one if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Sorry @JimJimson, forgot to post my reply when I found the solution. Posted it just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution.

Had to pass a variable with a function inside.

```
function confirm() {
    let eventListener=function(event) {
        {... execute what need to be done ...}

        //Unlisten after execution
        mdcAlert.unlisten("MDCDialog:closing", eventListener);
    };

    mdcAlert.open();
    mdcAlert.listen("MDCDialog:closing", eventListener);
}
```